# Docker build error: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?

Tags: docker, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment, circleci

I need a simple solution to build a docker image, push it to ECR, and deploy it to ECS.

The final part, which deploys the ECR image to ECS is working. (I'm using a `deploy.py` short script that uses Python's AWS boto3 SDK, found it easier than making the ECS Orb work..)

However, I'm struggling with the first part, need help. I just need to automate the simple `docker build`, `docker tag` and `docker push`. It's very simple, but I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Can anyone help me? It follows the code, I'm running it locally for debug purposes:

```yaml
version: '2.1'
jobs:
  build:
    docker:
      - image: cimg/python:3.8 
    environment:
      AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: yadayadayada
      AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: yadayadayada
      AWS_DEFAULT_REGION: yadayadayada
    steps:
      - checkout
      - run: |
          docker build -t myimg .
          docker tag myimg:latest asdf.dkr.ecr.asdf.amazonaws.com/asddf:latest
          docker push asdf.dkr.ecr.asdf.amazonaws.com/asdf:latest
          
          pip install boto3
          python deploy.py
```

Learnign CircleCI is really frustrating, no good resources for beginners...

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use the `setup_remote_docker` special step in order to get a remote Docker engine running so that your Docker commands will work.

> Learnign CircleCI is really frustrating, no good resources for beginners...

Really? You can find my answer (the "setup_remote_docker") and how to use it right on CircleCI Docs in a guide called [Running Docker Commands](https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/building-docker-images/).

I hope this helps. Also, you'll see that setting a Docker version is optional but I strongly suggest you set one. The default version is very old.

Comment: I have setup_remote_docker but am still getting this err.  Any ideas what could be wrong? It works locally on my machine but not on the circleci server.